# how to grep for the line with multiple keywords and make it into csv

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

With this command:

```
cmd param | grep 'foo1\|foo5\|foo7'
```

I get

```
foo1=bar1
foo5=bar5
foo7=bar7
```

how do I make this output write to a csv file ?

ultimately i would like to run the command in a loop with param changing for each loop ( hence the output) so it will be helpful if the file becomes like :

```
cat output.csv
    foo1=bar1, foo5=bar5, foo7=bar7
    foo1=value, foo5=value, foo7=value
```

Comment: If you show us a sample of the output of `cmd param` someone may be able to suggest a more elegant way to get the output you want more directly

Answer (score 2):

Would this works for you :

```
cmd param | grep 'foo1\|foo5\|foo7' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

- `tr '\n' ','` replace every line return with a ','
- `sed 's/,$//'` remove the last character if it's a ','

And if you want to put it in a csv file you can add an '\n' at the end of the line then redirect it to a csv file :

```
cmd param | grep 'foo1\|foo5\|foo7' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,\?$/\n/' >> file.csv
```

- `sed 's/,\?$/\n/'` Will remove the last char if it is a ',' and add an '\n'
- `>>` is used to add at the end of your csv file without removing what is already inside

Comment: I think you could combine the two `sed`s to `sed 's/,\?$/\n/'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one-liner:

```
echo $(cmd param | grep 'foo1\|foo5\|foo7') | sed 's/ /, /g' | tee -a output.csv
```

The command: `echo $(cmd param | grep 'foo1\|foo5\|foo7')` will print the output in linear form.

This puts a comma in between the variables: `sed 's/ /, /g'`

This appends the output to a new line at the end of the file: `tee -a output.csv`

Comment: Piping into `xargs` would probably be a nicer way than `echo` plus process substitution...

Comment: @ByteCommander Awesome, thanks! I will try this in the future and will probably edit this later.  I use this `echo` trick a lot so this should help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl you can, get the pattern, join it, and print it for all desired files:

```
perl -0nE 'say join(",",/(foo\d+=\w+)/g)' ex* > out
```

This will avoid your external loop